# curl verbose connected to not seen

Tags: curl

Using curl 7.28.0, informational text infos (Connected to) are not seen when I use verbose option

```
curl -vL http://192.168.2.100/test -trace-ascii --trace-time -i
11:33:43.011851 > GET /test HTTP/1.1
11:33:43.011851 > User-Agent: curl/7.28.0
11:33:43.011851 > Host: 192.168.2.100
11:33:43.011851 > Accept: */*
11:33:43.011851 > 
11:33:43.015125 < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: Note: `-trace-ascii` is not `--trace-ascii` and the latter also needs a file name after it...

Answer (score 0):

try this command 
    curl -v http://192.168.2.100/test -trace-ascii --trace-time -i

Comment: even with this command, I didn't get the following line: 
*   Trying 192.168.2.100...
* Connected to 192.168.2.100 (192.168.2.100) port 80 (#0)

Answer (score 0):

We need just to enable verbose when we compile curl package